# Suddenly all but 30 of my kittens vanished and none were working

Tags: kittens-game

I had 68 kittens, but when I changed screens and went back, suddenly I only had 30 and none of them were working, anyone know why? (Catnip production is always 200+ a second) Village is 1908 years old

Comment: Did they starve?

Comment: They couldn't have? Even at -90% my catnip production is +100, so I'm not sure how they could have managed to starve

Comment: Did you reload the screen without saving? If so, you went back to the last save-point.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely due to the bug in the KS.

http://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/36dysg/kitten_scientists_bug/